# utorrent download process

Tags: downloads, utorrent

How can I download any file using utorrent server?
I have already installed utorrent in my machine.[image: utorrent server]

Answer (score 0):

In order to download files through any torrent client you need to find the .TORRENT (hosted on many websites)

You do not need to use the uTorrent client, as with most Linux builds (I'm aware of) the Transmission BitTorrent Client is already installed.

Here's a how to for starters.
[https://www.wikihow.com/Download-With-uTorrent]